# Source for Lokaśaraṇaṃ Vyākaraṇam ( लोकशरणं व्याकरणम् )

Tags: reference-request, patanjali, panini

While listening to  *Pāṇiníya Aṣṭādhyāyī* ( पाणिनीय अष्टाध्यायी ) [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdvRS3dZP77JM-1IKkXjZHqVrp_eOqL4r), the quote *Lokaśaraṇaṃ Vyākaraṇam* ( लोकशरणं व्याकरणम् ) was attributed to *Patañjali* ( पतञ्जलि ) but I haven't been able to find it in *Patañjali's Mahābhāṣyam* ( पतञ्जलि महाभाष्यम् ) commentary on the *Aṣṭādhyāyī* ( अष्टाध्यायी ) .
Please help me find the same.